# My linux thinkpad is not charging when connected to AC

Tags: thinkpad, adapter, charging

The manufacturer of the adapter said I need to update my drivers and send me a link to install this https://www.iobit.com/en/driver-booster.php

I'm Linux based so it's not an option.

The adapter is Zendure Passport III and the notebook is Thinkpad L14.

Comment: Try a Lenovo adapter and that should work.

Comment: Driver Booster is not recommended for anyone, it's … ermm.. not good. Essence of snake, dab behind ears to cure all ills.

Comment: thank you @John I have a Lenovo adapter. I am asking this question not because I cannot find anything to charge my laptop with, but because I paid over 50$ for a charger that was supposed to work with all of my devices.

Comment: I have a Lenovo laptop running Windows that tends to forget how to charge every once in a while. The fix is usually to remove and reinstall the battery drivers, but at other times I need to disconnect and reconnect the batter cable inside the laptop. I'd would suggest you try that if you haven't yet.